# what is the linux command for creating an anonymous pipe(unnamed pipe)

Tags: c, linux

Want to create an unnamed pipe. On ubuntu 14, i tried "pipe", did not work, and can not find out with the internet search. For the named pipe,  "mkfifo" works.

Comment: An unnamed pipe gets created automatically for you, by the shell, when you execute a pipeline. P.S. What does this have to do with C++?

Comment: Are you trying to create a pipe programmatically, or in the shell?

Comment: Given the tags, I would guess he wants to do it programmatically on a linux system. J.C., this is a C article, not C++, but perhaps it can get you started down the right path: http://tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node11.html

Comment: trying to create a pipe in the shell.@user132278

Answer (score 1):

An anonymous pipe (a.k.a. a "pipe", since pipes are anonymous) is created by the shell when you use the `|` operator:

```
grep example . -r | less
```

You can't create a pipe with one command and then use it with another command later, not without some wacky `/proc` trickery.  If you need to use something later, you have to have some name to refer to it, at which point it's no longer a pipe.  Just be sure to connect each end in the right order (read before write).

Under the hood, a pipe is created as a pair of open file handles using the `pipe()` function.  After calling `pipe()`, the shell creates two subprocesses, and each subprocess selects the appropriate end of the pipe before calling `exec()`.  In general, it's not possible to replace shell builtins with your own programs.  Other examples are `cd` and `export`.

You can create pipes yourself in a program using `pipe()`.